# how to start workflow for bundle using core service?

Tags: core-service, workflow, bundles

I've read the question/answer of [how to start bundle workflow by event system](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/how-to-start-workflow-proces-for-a-bundle) and I've leveraged the stuff here to create bundle and add items via core service. But, I can't quite figure out how to start workflow on a bundle. I see the StartWorkflow method in ICoreService2012. but that doesn't accept a bundle. That expects the ID of a repository and StartWorkflowInstructionData. Am I able to use StartWorkflowInstructionData to specify the bundle to start the workflow?

Comment: yes Frank. thanks for the link... was in a rush to get it posted and should have taken the time to be more thorough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 StartWorkflowInstructionData startWorkflowInstruction = new StartWorkflowInstructionData();
 startWorkflowInstruction.Assignee = new LinkToTrusteeData { IdRef = client.GetCurrentUser().Id };
 startWorkflowInstruction.ActivityTitle = "A title for the activity";
 startWorkflowInstruction.ProcessInstanceTitle = "A title for the process instance";
 startWorkflowInstruction.Subjects = new[] { new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData { IdRef = bundle.Id } };
 client.StartWorkflow("THE_URI_OF_PUBLICATION", startWorkflowInstruction, new ReadOptions());
```

Basically the `StartWorkflowInstructionData` has an array of `Subjects`, you just add your bundle to that collection.