# Getting Oracle error while force finishing a workflow

Tags: core-service, workflow, bundles

I used the link [how to start workflow for bundle using core service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-start-workflow-for-bundle-using-core-service) and wrote the below code.

```
private bool StartWorkflow(VirtualFolderData bundledata, out string processInstanceID)
    {
        bool isStarted = false;
        processInstanceID = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string processdefID = GetContextualProcessDefinitionIDByName(objClient, "Publish Bundle Workflow", bundledata.LocationInfo.ContextRepository.Title);
            StartWorkflowInstructionData workflowInstruction = new StartWorkflowInstructionData() { ProcessInstanceTitle = "Publishing the Bundle " + bundledata.Title};                
            workflowInstruction.Subjects = new[] { new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData() { IdRef = bundledata.Id } };
            workflowInstruction.ProcessDefinition = new LinkToProcessDefinitionData() { IdRef = processdefID };
            ProcessInstanceData pid = (ProcessInstanceData)objClient.StartWorkflow(bundledata.LocationInfo.ContextRepository.IdRef, workflowInstruction, new ReadOptions());
            processInstanceID = pid.Id;
            Log(FormatDate() + "Publish Bundle Workflow process has been initiated!!!!!! Title - " + pid.Title);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pid.Id)) isStarted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(FormatDate() + "Exception during Starting the workflow with message : " + ex.Message);
        }

        return isStarted;
    }
```

and then based on the Process Instance ID I'm tring to force finish the workflow process.

```
string workFlowProcessID = string.Empty;
                                 if (StartWorkflow(bundledata, out workFlowProcessID))
                                 {
                                     Log(FormatDate() + "Bundle has been sent to workflow!!! Process Instance ID - " + workFlowProcessID);
                                     objClient.ForceFinishProcess(workFlowProcessID, liveApprovalStatusID, objReadOptions);
                                     Log(FormatDate() + "Force Finishing the workflow");
                                 }
```

My process instance is created but there is no bunlde attached to it. And while doing the force finish I'm facing and oracle error.

> Exception in Perform Testing() A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "TCM_WORKFLOW.ARCHIVE_PROCESS_INSTANCE ".
>   ORA-02292: integrity constraint (TCMDBUSER.FK_WFL_ACT_INST_PROC_INST) violated - child record found
>   ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.TCM_WORKFLOW", line 1023
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

This isssue is intermittent and sometimes the code works absolutely fine. 
I can force finish the process manually from CME.

Please advice if I'm missing something.

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to finish a process that includes a new (less than version 1.0) item that has been published?

Comment: Yes actually. I'm attaching a newly created page to the bundle but the page is in minor version.

Comment: If this new page has been published anywhere, then the workflow cannot finish because that implies cancelling changes. On items with version > 1.0, this is easy: just rollback. On new items this means the item must be deleted. Because it is published, it cannot be deleted... getting you on a catch-22 of Business Rule conflict. The only way around this is to first unpublish the page, then finish the process.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind trying to force finish a workflow immediately after starting it? Is the first activity an automated activity? In that case you may be force fiinishing the workflow while the automated activity is in progress

Comment: The idea is to create automated test cases using core service to test workflows. I need to end the workflow manually to ensure that the page goes through entire life cycle. And NO the first activity is not automated. @NunoLinhares : I removed all the predefined activities on the page that I was creating and ensured that it is in version 1.0 before I add it to the bundle but still I face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your use/test case is rather extreme, the mentioned error should not occur and hints at a product defect. Consider contacting SDL Customer Support to get it analyzed further.